# Blue screen of death when installing XP on HP dv6-3007tu notebook

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I have a [HP Pavilion dv6-3007tu notebook](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=4219946). When I try to install Windows XP on the machine a blue screen of death will be displayed during the installation process. How can I fix this problem?

Machine configuration is:

- Intel Core i3-350M CPU
- 3GB RAM

Comment: See the 3rd post in this thread for instructions...http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-systems-and/General-XP-Downgrade-Guide-for-HP-Laptops/td-p/83267

Answer (score 1):

May be you have SATA hard drive and some earlier windows xp versions doesn't support SATA HD so get windows XP SP3,or enable IDE option from BIOS

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message exactly? Sounds like you need to enable IDE mode for your hard drive though, based on my psychic predictions.